# Передать список значений рандомной длины в хранимую процедуру MYSQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким способом можно передать список значений в хранимую процедуру MySQL(8.0).

Задача выглядит следующим образом:
Парсер обходит сайт и формирует список из опубликованных объявлений каждое из которых имеет некий идентификатор (к примеру VIN номер),

Существует процедура которая записывает в базу параметры этих объявлений.

Теперь собственно вопрос. как передать в другую процедуру сформированный (в каком либо виде) список идентификаторов для того, что-бы процедура выполнила запрос:

```
DELETE FROM units WHERE vin NOT IN ('WDB96340310000000', 'WDB96340310000000', ...)
```

Тоесть я понимаю, что сформировать SQL_query в коде и передать его это не проблема.
К примеру для python3

```py
values = ['WDB96340310000000', 'WDB96340310000000', ...]
db.cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM units WHERE vin NOT IN ({', '.join(values)});")
```

> Но на данный момент интересна сама возможность передачи списка значений в хранимую процедуру MySQL

Тоесть, что-бы вызов выглядел так:

```py
values = ['WDB96340310000000', 'WDB96340310000000', ...]
db.cursor.execute(f"call SOME_PROCEDURE({some_formated_data_var});")
```

> Я понимаю, что по сути разницы никакой, но все же...

Comment: Передать в виде JSON-array, a в запросе разобрать на записи функцией JSON_TABLE().

Comment: @Akina. Вас не затруднит несколько поподробней? Я только осваиваю SQL. Ну или хотя-бы ссылочку на источник с подробной информацией и примерами.

Comment: Вот [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093413/229437) я показываю, как разобрать JSON-массив на записи. Задача там другая, но для изучения это даже полезно - понять, как оно работает, на совсем чужой задаче...

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо Вам огромное, вы меня в который раз выручаете. За отправную точку точно пойдет.